# load view form StoryBoard that does not have a Segue

Tags: ipad, ios5, uistoryboard

I am really liking having all of my view's laid out in the Storyboard but there are times when I will have a view that is shown based on a button that is generated by code so there will be no Segue reference - it will be totally disconnected in the Storyboard.  I would still like to design it in the storyboard though so I can have a nice overview of all my screens.

Is it possible for me to load the XIB (or whatever it is in a storyboard) designed in the storyboard when a UIViewControler is loaded?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what are you trying to do ? what kind of data is responsible for the creation of the new
view ? In general i sugest you create a new class or yust a view whit the same class and depending on the user entery you hide or genereate the view content .
It'l be easyer for you to

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do this in my projects:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

Just make sure you have set your controller's identifier correctly. You can do this by:

1. selecting the controller in Storyboard
2. in the Utilities panel, click the Attributes inspector. Whatever you decide to put in the Identifier field is what goes in the 'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier' statement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for - thanks.  Although it is is not totally necessary it is nice to see all of my UIViews on one screen.

Comment: Initially it didn't workout, but then..

`[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NO];` did the magic for me in the last line.

Comment: Yes Mayu, it should be noted that using [self.navigationController push...] only works if that view controller is embedded in a navigation view controller.

Answer (score 3):

You must assign a **Storyboard ID** to your view controller.

*IB > Show the Identity inspector > Identity > Storyboard ID*

[image: Storyboard ID]

## Swift

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController")
                     as? UIViewController
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: The screenshot helps me. Thanks